# Google map api - autocomplete (japanese)

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete

When I search for Ljubljana i got suggestion: Ljubljana, リュブリャナ, Slovenia. And this happens on other cities too (Velenje, ベレニエ, Slovenia,...). So I need help to bypass that or somehow correct it. (I need autocomplete for my project)

Here you can test for yourself: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Works fine and in english for me, you may try overriding the language settings when you include the api in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en">
```

Comment: if i change to language=en like u said nothing changes. Japanese is still there.

<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en&libraries=places"    type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Other than that I have no idea as that the only language option I'm aware of.  I notice I can search for 'ベ' and it'll complete japanese place names even on the 'en' version, you may want to check that you're not passing anything that could be interpreted as kana, and perhaps do a geoip search on the ip address you're being assigned.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the data quality related issue as I have very similar situation, look here: [Google Maps api v3 autocomplete weird characters in result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853706/google-maps-api-v3-autocomplete-weird-characters-in-result) I have reported this to Google, but they have pointed out that it's related to data, so it was reported back to the data provider (in my case Teleatlas).