# Google Maps api v3 autocomplete weird characters in result

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Autocomplete returns unknown characters for some addresses in results, this problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910417/google-map-api-autocomplete-japanese) as well, but without any answer. I was investigating this and unfortunately haven't found any working example. To reproduce, go to the https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete and enter for example "Dobra trefa", you'll should get this *"Dobrá trefa, Koněvova, ジシュコフ, Prague-Prague 3, Czech Republic"* - i.e. some japanese/chinese symbols (not sure). I've tried the same name on Google Maps and it works just perfect, but it looks like Google Maps are still using api v2 so that doesn't really help. I'm really stuck with this, have tried the following:

1.) adding charset="UTF-8" to the script tag 
2.) adding  into the <head> <meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"> to enforce page encoding
3.) adding language=en to the javascript URI for Google Maps API
4.) checking what is being sent to the server when I type into autocomplete
5.) checking how Google Maps work
6.) googling for the similar questions
7.) looking for working solutions

without any result.

What am I doing wrong? Could it be connected with machine/browser/configuration?

P.S. Not posting my code here, because it's just the copy of example for autocomplete from Google official dev site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproduced. I reckon this is a bug, which you should report in the Issues tracker: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=autocomplete (do check that none of the existing Issues relate to this: if you find one, star it rather than add another).

As the other answer notes, the odd characters are Japanese. You might want to reference both questions here (and any relevant addresses) in your bug report.

Comment: Bug reported http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4186&q=autocomplete&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal , hopefully it will be resolved soon.